# WPS request builder missing in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wps

[image: GeoServer Demos screenshot]

I'm using GeoServer 2.10.1 and I need to use gs_clip function but I am not able to find WPS request builder in the GeoServer Demos.

Comment: did you install the WPS plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshot, you either:

- did not install the WPS plugin
- you installed it, but then did not restart GeoServer

Comment: Here's instructions to install: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wps/install.html